# How to add timestamp to video with different date & time format provided by android?

Tags: java, android, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I am making android app to add timestamp to video using FFMPEG library and also it works fine but it add timestamp using by default date time format provided by FFMPEG.

[image: Video Screenshot]

it's uses `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` format for timestamp

where android provide different date & time format [Click here for examples](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat#examples)

ex: I want to use `"EEE, MMM d, ''yy"` date format for timestamp.

How to do that?

I an using this FFMPEG Command:

`ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -vf "drawtext=fontfile=roboto.ttf:fontsize=36:fontcolor=yellow:text='%{pts\:gmtime\:1456007118}'" -preset ultrafast -f mp4 output.mp4`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ffmpeg calls strftime from the system's linked C library to generate the formatted string, so what's possible will depend on what your available strftime function can do.

That said, this is the closest I can get, using MinGW strftime

```
text='%{pts\:gmtime\:1456007118\:%a, %b %d, %y}'
```

which produces

```
Sat, Feb 20, 16
```

Comment: what is %a,%b,%d,%y?

Comment: how to customize command for other date & time format? Is there any other attributes like %a 7 %b in FFMPEG?

Comment: Those are strftime format specifiers.See http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html for specifiers available on linux.

Comment: when i try to print colon between %H and %M is show me error because i want to print hours:Minutes ex: 06:25